# What is Stdev of WRK test, which is better?

Tags: performance

I ran a wrk test and result came as follows

```
root@wrk:~# wrk -c100 -t12 -d30s http://104.x.x.190  
Running 30s test @ http://104.x.x.190
  12 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    49.14ms  111.33ms   1.09s    97.09%
    Req/Sec   250.34     31.06   313.00     89.19%
  55509 requests in 30.06s, 25.05MB read
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 55509
Requests/sec:   1846.52
Transfer/sec:    853.23KB
```

What is **Stdev** here? Is higher better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stddev is [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) - a measure of how much the members of a set deviate from the mean value of the group. For latency I would say smaller is better as it means that $thing is taking the same time each time it is measured.